# Create custom ggplot2 function that combines theme and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am often using the theme_hc() theme (from the package ggthemes) in ggplot2 graphs, combined with scale_colour_pander() or scale_fill_pander(). I want to make a custom function now called myTheme that combines these three functions into one.

I tried the following

```
myTheme <- function(){
  theme_hc() + scale_colour_pander() + scale_fill_pander()
}
data <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + myTheme()
```

But apparently R evaluates this first inside the function and gives an error: 'Error: Don't know how to add scale_colour_pander() to a theme object'.

Then I tried

```
myTheme <- function(){
  ggplot() + theme_hc() + scale_colour_pander() + scale_fill_pander()
}
data <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + myTheme()
```

Which returns: 'Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot'

Is there a way to achieve the desired effect or should I keep combining the individual commands?

Comment: try `list( theme_hc() , scale_colour_pander() , scale_fill_pander())`

Comment: This works! Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: takje, I am somewhat new to SO (comments) but I think your request to add the answer needed to include @baptiste for him to get the message (i.e. w/o having to check back by chance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the standard technique is to wrap those elements in a list,

```
p + list( theme_hc() , scale_colour_pander() , scale_fill_pander())
```